# What method does Monospace use for encryption?

Tags: applications, encryption

This [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.underwood.monospace&hl=en&gl=US) has the ability to encrypt.
What method does Monospace use for encryption?

Comment: A well designed security application would have a public documentation where the used encryption scheme is presented.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the decompiled source code I would not call it "encryption".

Instead "encrypted" texts are simply the markdown text encoded using base64 plus the SHA-256 hashed password appended to it:

From `com.underwood.monospace.main.MainActivityFragment.encryptText()` :

```
 this.mEncryptedText = Utils.base64Encode(new SpannableToMarkdown(
    new WeakReference(getActivity())).toMarkdown(this.mEditText.getText())) + 
    "\n" + this.mHashedPassword;
```